# using derived class data members from base class method

Tags: c++, inheritance

So i have been trying to use derived class data members from the base class and i am not able to figure out how to do that. I see a way to do this as just passing the member i need in parameter when i call the base class method but i was just thinking that there should be another way to do that. So i have replicated this as below.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class B;
class A{
    public:
    display(){
        cout<<cord<<endl;
    }
    int cord = 25;
};

class B : public A{
    public:
    B(){
        A a;
        a.display();
    }
    int cord = 30;
};

class C : public A{
    public:
    C(){
        A a;
        a.display();
    }
    int cord = 35;
};

int main(){
    B b;
    C c;
    B.display();

}
```

The above code as giving output as

```
25
25
25
```

What i want it to give out is

```
30
35
30
```

Every way to do this will be appreciated, whatever is better and if you want to me add something or anything ask in comments, i'll do right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

define a virtual getter like

```
virtual int getCord() const { return cord; }
```

in each class and call it in *display*

```
void display(){ cout << getCord() <<endl; }
```

and in the constructor of B and C you also need to replace

> ```
> A a;
> a.display();
> ```

just by

```
display();
```

else there is no chance you access to the value of the sub classes explicitly calling display on an instance of A

---

> using derived class data members from base class method

This is because of that I let the redefinition of *cord* in B and C, but I do not recommend you to do that kind of redefinition in 'real' codes ;-)

Comment: to elaborate a bit on @bruno answer, now that you know about virtual, consider a virtual `display` function specific to each class that knows about the class details and that uses the class members.

Comment: @neu-rah yes this an other way. The initial code of the OP is so _strange_

Comment: @neu-rah anyway I not follow that solution because the OP wants "_using derived class data members from base class method_", and to call the display of B in an operation of B and same for C is far of the OP request ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Lets take the `B` constructor:

```
B(){
    A a;
    a.display();
}
```

In it you create a completely separate object `a` of type `A`, and call `display` on it. That `display` call will be using the `a` object, not knowing anything about the `B` class or its totally separate `cord` member variable at all.

One possible way to solve this is to create a constructor of `A` that takes the value of `cord` as an argument, pass the "correct" value in the `B` constructor initializer list, and then call the `display` function on *this* object:

```
struct A{
    A() = default;

    explicit A(int c)
        : cord(c)
    {
    }

    display(){
        cout<<cord<<endl;
    }

    int cord = 25;
};

struct B : A{
    B()
        : A(30)
    {
        display();  // Equivalent to this->display();
    }
};
```

Of course, you need to do something similar for the `C` class (or structure).

Note that I removed the member variable `cord` from the `B` class. That's because if you declare a new member variable with the same name as a member variable in a base class, then you effectively create a completely new member variable that is unrelated to the one in the parent class. And for the simple example you show there's no need to "override" the member variable, as it already exists in all child-classes as well.

Comment: hello, removing _cord_ from B and C there is not anymore "_derived class data members_" (it is a base class member) so it is not "_using derived class data members from base class method_" as requested by the OP, no ? ;-) You corrected the strangeness from the OP code, but you do not answer to the question finally ... if I well understand ^^